# File($.stack).parent gives a bad result in VSCode extendscript debugger

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, extendscript

I am trying to access the parent folder fullPath from a JSX extendscript script. So when I try to do:

```
$.write(File($.stack).parent.fsName);
```

I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects 2020\Support Files
```

However when I run this from After effects itself (go to file => scripts => run script) I get the **actual** parent folder's path.

I believe this has something to do with VSCode itself.

My bet is VSCode does not execute the JSX file, but copies its contents to a hidden file in *After Effects/ Support Files/* and executes that instead.
Any idea on how to fix the issue?

Comment: I'm not an expert in AE, so just a guess. You could try to get the folder this way: `File((Folder(app.activeScript)).parent`

Comment: And this looks quite plausible that VSCode runs scripts in kinda sandbox and supplies them with wrong/dummy environment variables. If so, you can't fix it. You can only implement a some workaround. VSCode is not exactly a native environment to run jsx scripts after all.

Comment: Yeah, I can't find a workaround. I guess I'll have to just ignore this problem for now and focus on other things,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering, even after running the command:

```
afterfx -r C:/Users/me/myscript.jsx
```

from the command line, I still face the exact same issue.
I believe the vscode extension that I'm using is copying the contents of my script over to the after effects installation path where afterfx.exe exists and then running some sort of bat file with a similar command.
But I can at least be assured that when my script is run from the AE app, it'll yield the correct parent path.